# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core' while PyCharm can run 'core.py'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, package

So I was trying to install a package called 'gdsCAD', and this is where I ended up:

> C:\Anaconda\python.exe
> "C:/Users/HUANG/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/trial1.py"
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/HUANG/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/trial1.py", line
> 2, in 
> import gdsCAD
>
> File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gdsCAD\_*init*_.py", line 26, in
>
> import core
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

And these are the first lines of '_*init*_.py' which runs fine:

```
import core
import shapes
import utils
import templates
```

I can also find the 'core.py' in the same folder which also runs fine. Somehow all these files can run individually, but error occurs when I import the whole package. Could you please shed some lights on it? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install `gdsCAD` in the correct environment?

Comment: Did you run it from the correct folder, so C:/Users/HUANG/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/

Comment: Chris: Yes, as you can see, it is the base environment of Anaconda, and actually the import was successful using Spyder under the base environment.

Comment: Tim: Yes, they were run under the same environment though they are in the folder of the environment.